# how to make a url variable available to all the template

Tags: django, templates

I have a specific requirement - say I hit the url as below -

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/brand_product_list/1
```

in the above url the last 1 is a brand-id and I need this brand-id to be available to all the templates for eg. if I call

my brand_product_list looks like below in views.py -

```
# Product List as per Brand1
def brand_product_list(request,brand_id):
    brandid = brand_id
    brand_b=Brand.objects.get(id=brand_id)    
    cats_b=Product.objects.filter(brand=brand_b).distinct().values('category__title','category_id')
    data_b=Product.objects.filter(brand=brand_b).order_by('-id')
    colors_b=ProductAttribute.objects.filter(brand=brand_b).distinct().values('color__title','color__id','color__color_code')
    sizes_b=ProductAttribute.objects.filter(brand=brand_b).distinct().values('size__title','size__id')
    flavors_b=ProductAttribute.objects.filter(brand=brand_b).distinct().values('flavor__title','flavor__id')
    
    return render(request,'brand_product_list.html',
    {
        'data_b':data_b,
        'brandid':brandid,
        'cats_b':cats_b,
        'brand_b':brand_b,
        'sizes_b':sizes_b,
        'colors_b':colors_b,
        'flavors_b':flavors_b,
    })
```

in the above code I need brandid to be available in cart.html which is called from clicking cart button in base.html which is extended in brand_product_list.html

point is since base.html is extended in brand_product_list.html, the brandid is available to base.html (means child variable available in parent) and I can filter stuff based on brand but somehow when I click on cart button in base.html, the same brandid is not taken to cart.html even though base.html is extended in cart.html (means parent variable not available in child).

I tried include as below

```
{% include "./brand_product_list.html" %}
```

but since in brand_product_list.html, there is some filter.html, it throws error that argument is not available --

```
NoReverseMatch at /cart
Reverse for 'filter_data_b' with arguments '('brandid',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['filter_data_b/(?P<brand_id>[0-9]+)$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart
Django Version: 3.2.8
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'filter_data_b' with arguments '('brandid',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['filter_data_b/(?P<brand_id>[0-9]+)$']
Exception Location: C:\Users\j1011470\Documents\Personal\Business\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py, line 694, in _reverse_with_prefix
Python Executable:  C:\Users\j1011470\Documents\Personal\Business\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.8
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\j1011470\\Documents\\Personal\\Business\\Pitaara',
```

I request you to please help in this situation..

Any possibility of using context_processor with request and one argument ? or some other way...

---

cart.html which gets called on the click on cart button in base.html is below -

```
{% extends './base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<script src="{% static 'custom.js' %}"></script>
<main class="container my-4" id="cartList">
    <!-- Featured Products -->
    <h3 class="my-4 border-bottom pb-1">Cart ({{totalitems}})</h3>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for product_id,item in cart_data.items %}
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="/media/{{item.image}}" width="50" />
                    <p><a href="/product/{{item.title|slugify}}/{{product_id}}">{{item.title}}</a></p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" class="product-qty-{{product_id}}" value="{{item.qty}}" style="vertical-align: bottom;" />
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary update-item" data-item="{{product_id}}"><i class="bi bi-arrow-clockwise"></i></button>
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger delete-item" data-item="{{product_id}}"><i class="bi bi-trash"></i></button>
                </td>
                <td>$ {{item.price}}</td>
                <td>$ {% widthratio item.price 1 item.qty %}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                <th>Total</th>
                <th>Rs. {{total_amt}}</th>
            </tr>
            {% if totalitems %}
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" align="right">
                    <a href="/" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm">Checkout <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-alt-right"></i></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endif %}
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</main>
{% endblock %}
```

base.html is below

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>{% block title %}Delicious Doughnuts{% endblock %}</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.6.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white border-bottom">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Delicious</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse"
                    aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
                        {% if brandid %}
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="/brand_product_list/{{brandid}}">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="/brand_product_list/{{brandid}}">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        {% elif cart_data.items %}
                        {% for productid, item in cart_data.items %}
                        {% if forloop.first %}
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="/brand_product_list/{{item.brandid}}">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}                        
                        {% endif %}                            
                    </ul>                    
                    <form class="d-flex">
                        <a aria-current="page" href="{% url 'cart' %}"><i class="bi bi-cart3" style="font-size: 1.5rem; color: cornflowerblue;"></i>Cart (<span class="cart-list">{{request.session.cartdata|length}}</span>)</a>
                        <ul>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                              <i class="bi bi-user"></i> My Account
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="d">Dashboard</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
                            {% else %}
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
                              <a class="dropdown-item" href="Signup">Signup</a>
                            {% endif %}
                            </div>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                    </form>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
    </header>

    <div id="content">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>

    <footer class="pt-4 my-md-5 pt-md-5 border-top container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-md">
            <a href="#">Delicious Doughnuts</a>
            <small class="d-block mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2017-2020</small>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-md">
            <h5>Features</h5>
            <ul class="list-unstyled text-small">
                <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Cool stuff</a></li>
                <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Random feature</a></li>
                <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Team feature</a></li>
                <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Stuff for developers</a></li>
                <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Another one</a></li>
                <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Last time</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-md">
            <h5>Resources</h5>
            <ul class="list-unstyled text-small">
                <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Resource</a></li>
                <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Resource name</a></li>
                <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Another resource</a></li>
                <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Final resource</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-md">
            <h5>About</h5>
            <ul class="list-unstyled text-small">
                <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Team</a></li>
                <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Locations</a></li>
                <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Privacy</a></li>
                <li><a class="text-muted" href="#">Terms</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

also the base.html code has href="{% url 'cart' %}" for which the url.py is

```
path('cart',views.cart_list,name='cart'),
```

views.py having above cart_list.html is -

```
# Cart List Page
def cart_list(request):
    total_amt=0
    if 'cartdata' in request.session:
        for p_id,item in request.session['cartdata'].items():
            total_amt+=int(item['qty'])*float(item['price'])
        return render(request, 'cart.html',{'cart_data':request.session['cartdata'],'totalitems':len(request.session['cartdata']),'total_amt':total_amt})
    else:
        return render(request, 'cart.html',{'cart_data':'','totalitems':0,'total_amt':total_amt})
```

Comment: Can you share the code for `cart.html` template & for the view that renders it?

Comment: added the cart.html and also the flow upto an extent if that helps....

Answer (score 0):

I tried stuff, some worked some didn't - I feel the way to do is to save the brandid in the session, the moment the url is hit like below -

```
# Product List as per Brand1
def brand_product_list(request,brand_id):
    request.session['prod_brand'] = brand_id
    brandid = brand_id
    brand_b=Brand.objects.get(id=brand_id)    
    cats_b=Product.objects.filter(brand=brand_b).distinct().values('category__title','category_id')
    data_b=Product.objects.filter(brand=brand_b).order_by('-id')
    colors_b=ProductAttribute.objects.filter(brand=brand_b).distinct().values('color__title','color__id','color__color_code')
    sizes_b=ProductAttribute.objects.filter(brand=brand_b).distinct().values('size__title','size__id')
    flavors_b=ProductAttribute.objects.filter(brand=brand_b).distinct().values('flavor__title','flavor__id')
    
    return render(request,'brand_product_list.html',
    {
        'data_b':data_b,
        'brandid':brandid,
        'cats_b':cats_b,
        'brand_b':brand_b,
        'sizes_b':sizes_b,
        'colors_b':colors_b,
        'flavors_b':flavors_b,
        'prodbrand':request.session['prod_brand'],
    })
```